# Java redirection + domain

Tags: apache, tomcat, dns, appdomain

I have the follow :

- Java application(testing.war)
- Tomcat 8
- Mysql
- Domain: test.com

In my VPS for redirection I use: apache + tomcat, if I write www.test.com/testing, it's works, but if I write www.test.com/, I saw the tomcat landing page

I need :

- if I write www.test.com/ => I can see my App
- Can I redirect my app without apache? (Only configuring tomcat 8)

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-name your WAR file to be `ROOT.war`.

Tomcat [uses the WAR filename as the context path](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html#Naming) when using auto-deploy. The easiest way to deploy your application on `/` is to re-name the WAR file to `ROOT.war` (case sensitive).